# pre- steps for python web developing?

Tags: python-3.x, web

Nowadays I am trying to proceed a self-learn python programming in order to get familiar with python web developing.  I have chosen my road map and I want to be a Python web developer. but my question is what are the prerequisites?

1. will some information about network be needed in my way?
2. what are the steps before starting web developing?
3. should I choose Django Framework or Flask?
4. Can you introduce the most comprehensive books in this subject?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the world of Python!

As I am that you know, that the answers to these questions are rather objective, but I will give my opinion on the matter.

1. It always good to have some perspective in the way the domain works, but you don't need in-depth knowledge on how a network is configured. The one important information is that you know that HTTP is stateless, and should be programmed as such.
2. Getting familiar with the basics, learn some HTML, CSS, and javascript. Then return a simple view from Python, and you are ready to explore the world of web developing.

https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-frameworks.html is a link worth visiting to get some understanding of the topic.

3. Flask and Django are two separate worlds. Django is a full-stack framework, whereas Flask is a Microframework. Flask is much simpler, so my tip is to start there unless you would like a challenge.
4. Take a look at this link; https://www.vandelaydesign.com/best-web-development-books/ it lists several books and some that are relevant for your case.